# How to repeat (adding loop) html elements with content in angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I want to repeat the following code block using angular or node.js

```
<div class="test-item col-sm-6">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="../../../../assets/image/ngozi.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <p>"Definitely worth the investment. Without sancoj, we would have gone bankrupt by now."</p>
    <div>
      <i class="material-icons checked">star</i>
      <i class="material-icons checked">star</i>
      <i class="material-icons checked">star</i>
      <i class="material-icons checked">star</i>
      <i class="material-icons checked">star</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some ideas?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor

Comment: Angular and nodejs are completely different things, maybe you must start from the beginning reading and understanding the differences to be able to make a decision.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `*ngFor`, for more details have a look at angular docs [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#ngforof),

```
<div class="test-item col-sm-6">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="../../../../assets/image/ngozi.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <p>"Definitely worth the investment. Without sancoj, we would have gone bankrupt by now."</p>
    <div>
      <i class="material-icons checked" *ngFor="let star in stars">{{star}}</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```